# The following packages have unmet dependencies from installing python3

Tags: apt, dependencies

I'm not very experienced with Ubuntu and when I started playing around with Python a year I assume I overwrote some important dependencies.

I made it even worse by trying to fix the issues and now I can't install or use nodejs which is essential for my work.

When I run `sudo apt update` I get the following error

```
Get:34 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [1.768 B]
Fetched 6.700 kB in 5s (1.312 kB/s)                        
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 11, in <module>
import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

When I run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` I get the following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 : Depends: gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 (>= 2.40.0) but 2.36.11-2 is installed
              Depends: gir1.2-pango-1.0 (>= 1.41.0) but 1.40.14-1ubuntu0.1 is installed
              Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.24.7) but 3.22.30-1ubuntu4 is installed
 python3-cairo : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is installed
 python3-gi : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is installed
          Depends: libgirepository-1.0-1 (>= 1.62.0-4~) but 1.56.1-1 is installed
 python3-gi-cairo : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is installed
 python3-markupsafe : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is installed
 python3-netifaces : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is installed
 python3-protobuf : Depends: libprotobuf17 but it is not installed
                Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is installed
 python3-reportlab-accel : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is installed
 python3-sip : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is installed
 python3-zope.interface : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Before it got to this state I saw that I had around 1600 outdated packages. I realize this isn't an easy issue to fix but any help would be greatly appreciated.

When trying to install `aptitude`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aptitude : Depends: aptitude-common (= 0.8.12-1ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 1.9.11~) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libboost-iostreams1.71.0 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libcwidget4 (>= 0.5.18-1) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libncursesw6 (>= 6.1+20180210) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libxapian30 (>= 1.4.14~) but 1.4.5-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 : Depends: gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 (>= 2.40.0) but 2.36.11-2 is to be installed
              Depends: gir1.2-pango-1.0 (>= 1.41.0) but 1.40.14-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
              Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.24.7) but 3.22.30-1ubuntu4 is to be installed
 python3-cairo : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
 python3-gi : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
          Depends: libgirepository-1.0-1 (>= 1.62.0-4~) but 1.56.1-1 is to be installed
 python3-gi-cairo : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
 python3-markupsafe : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
 python3-netifaces : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
 python3-protobuf : Depends: libprotobuf17 but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
 python3-reportlab-accel : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
 python3-sip : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
 python3-zope.interface : Depends: python3 (>= 3.8~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: How did exactly "I started playing around with Python "? Have you touch system Python3? Do you have installed Anaconda?

Comment: @N0rbert I will try this out later thank you.

Comment: @N0rbert I'm not sure but I assume I did touch it. I started playing around with Python scripting and installed some libraries a while ago. Only noticed an issue when I tried to update my system this week.

Answer (score 0):

You have a line that says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'`. You can try using solutions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708180/python-dev-installation-error-importerror-no-module-named-apt-pkg).

Another approach to handle unmet dependencies is to use `aptitude`. `aptitude` can make suggestions to fix the underlying problem.

```bsh
sudo apt install aptitude
sudo aptitude update
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It didn't work though. I updated my question with the results

Comment: I see. I guess you're in a pretty bad situation. Probably, it has something to do with python versions. Have you tried the solutions in the link I referred? Also take a look at the solutions here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56218562/how-to-fix-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-apt-pkg. One of them might solve your issue.